# Calling by reference on F#

Tags: f#

Is there an option to call a function by reference?

For example:
if I have a variable x in func1 and I want to send it to func2 so it can change it (without returning its new value etc.)

```
let func1 =
    let mutable x = 1
    func2 x
    System.Console.WriteLine(x)

let func2 x =
    x <- x + 1
```

So calling func1 will print "2"..

Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: As you can see, it's certainly possible to pass arguments by reference in F#.  However, as several of us have pointed out, this is very contrary to common idiom in functional programming. Not wrong per se--just uncommon.

Comment: cookya since you may be new to StackOverflow: it's generally considered good form to accept an answer by clicking on the check mark under the vote count on the left.  That way if others see your question and its answers they have some idea of which you consider the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `&` operator and `byref` keyword.

```
let func1 =
    …
    func2 (&x)
    …

let func2 (x : int byref) =
    …
```

See [MSDN: Reference cells (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The strict translation from C#-style code would be such:

```
let func2 (x : byref<_>) =
    x <- x + 1

let func1 =
    let mutable x = 1
    func2 &x
    System.Console.WriteLine(x)
```

But it is highly recommended to stick to references.

*Edit*: As was pointed out (see comments), you probably meant that func1 would be a function:

```
let func2 (x : byref<_>) =
    x <- x + 1

let func1 () =
    let mutable x = 1
    func2 &x
    System.Console.WriteLine(x)
```

Comment: Lazy-generics. It means the F# type-inference will guess what is supposed to be there (it'll guess `int`, so the type of x is `byref<int>`).

Comment: I think you need a `()` after `func1` - declared as it is now it is a value, not a function.

Comment: Though the name implies it is a function, it might not be. The original author probably did not notice, and I did not pay enough attention to verify his naming :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is possible but it's pretty much the opposite of the functional approach which F# encourages.  Is there some strong reason you can't do this:

```
let func2 x =
   x + 1

let func1() =
    let x = 1
    let y = func2 x
    System.Console.WriteLine(y)
```

This is the more idiomatic way to do this sort of thing in functional programming (and F#). Or if you must mutate x then how about this:

```
let func2 x =
   x + 1

let func1() =
    let mutable x = 1
    x <- func2 x
    System.Console.WriteLine(x)
```

By the way, in F#, func2 has to be defined *before* it's used.

Comment: Doesn't `func1` need a `()` in the declaration to be actually a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reference cells:

```
let func1 ref = 
  ref := !ref+1

let func2 () = 
  let x = ref 1
  func1 x
  System.Console.WriteLine(!x)
```

but it is not 'best practice' (to put it mildly) in a functional language to do these kind of things